# Use the value of =sheetname(2) as a reference for a formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I already know that if I put =sheetname(2) into a cell, I get the name of the 2nd sheetname into that cell.

What I want to do is to reference a cell in the 2nd sheet (dynamically, meaning a new sheet might be added and moved into the 2nd position).

For example, tab 1 is named "Current Status".  tab 2 is named by the date, for example (using last week) "7/30".  When a new week rolls around, tab 2 is copied (duplicated), the contents wiped out, and renamed with the current date, and moved into the 2nd position.  So now the 2nd tab is named "8/06" (thus the tabs provide a history).

On the 1st tab (named "Current Status"), I want the contents of cell B3 to show the value of what is in B3 of the 2nd tab, regardless of the name.  So last week it would have had `="7/30"!B3`.

I tried using `=sheetname(2)!B3` but that just gives me a formula parse error.
I also tried using `="=sheetname(2)"!B3`

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=INDIRECT(sheetname(2)&"!B3")
```